# Count entity after a entity manager save

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, transaction-isolation

community,

i have a problem to count entities after a entitymanager#save in the same transaction. The problem is, that i get always an inexpected count. I would like to count the current rows of a entity after a entitymanager save, but the result is always the current row count + the saved entity (which are not commited yet). It looks like a classic dirty read issue. 
For this reason i use Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW and Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ to count only the commited entities.
If I use a h2 database the result is the result which i expected, but if i use MYSQL there is another result.

Here some code snippets:

The service:

```
@Service
public class MyTestService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomeLogic() {
        entityRepository.save(new Entity());
        final long count = count();

        if (count != 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Entity count should be 0 but is " + count);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    public long count() {
        return entityRepository.count();
    }

}
```

The repo:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Entity> {

    // @Override
    // @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
    // isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    // long count();

}
```

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyTestService myTestService;

    @Test
    public void testEntityCounterWithMultiThreads() {
        myTestService.doSomeLogic();
    }

}
```

If i uncomment the repository code, all works, but I don't understand the difference.

Anybody knows where is my thinking blunder?